# How to make sure the value is reset in a 'foreach' loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I was writing a simple PHP page and a few `foreach` loops were used.

Here are the scripts:

```
$arrs = array("a", "b", "c");

foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    if(substr($arr,0,1)=="b") {
        echo "This is b";
    }     
} // End of first 'foreach' loop, and I didn't use 'ifelse' here.
```

And when this `foreach` ends, I wrote another `foreach` loop in which all the values in the `foreach` loop was the same as in the previous `foreach`.

```
foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    if(substr($arr,0,1)=="c") {
        echo "This is c";
    }     
}
```

I am not sure if it is a good practice to have two `foreach` loops with the same values and keys.

Will the values get overwritten in the first `foreach` loop?

Comment: The code indentation is terrible. Please make this more readable.

Comment: I've changed the code indenting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's OK until you start using references and then you can get strange behaviour, for example:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
//notice reference &
foreach ($array as & $item) {   }

$array2 = array(10, 11, 12, 13);
foreach ($array2 as $item) {   }

print_r($array);
```

Outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 13
)
```

Because the first foreach leaves `$item` as a reference to `$array[3]`, `$array[3]` is sequentially set to each value in `$array2`.

You can solve this be doing `unset($item)` after the first `foreach`, which will remove the reference, but **this isn't actually an issue in your case**, as you are not using references with foreach.

Comment: WOW. Had the exact issue as your sample code. Why does `$array[3]` sequentially set each value of `$array2`? What doesn't `$item` get updated?

Answer (score 6):

Two notable notes from the [documentation of `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Note: When `foreach` first starts executing, **the internal array pointer is automatically reset** to the first element of the array. This means that you do not need to call `reset()`  before a `foreach`  loop.

and

> Note: Unless the array is referenced, `foreach` operates **on a copy** of the specified array and not the array itself. `foreach` has some side effects on the array pointer. **Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the `foreach` without resetting it**.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not writing to the array, only reading from it and printing stuff out, no values in the array will be changed.

You can save time looping through the array twice though by doing this:

```
$arrs = array("a", "b", "c");

foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    if(substr($arr,0,1)=="b") {
        echo "This is b";
    }
    if(substr($arr,0,1)=="c") {
        echo "This is c";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is 1 foreach loop.

Or an even shorter approach to what Jon said, is this:

```
$arrs = array("a", "b", "c");

foreach ($arrs as $arr)
    if ($arr != "a")
        echo 'This is ' . $arr;
```

This is much easier and faster than using substr, since you are already using a foreach loop.  And try not to pollute it with a ton of if statements, if you find yourself doing this, it's better to use a switch statement, much faster.

Cheers :)