# How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, iteration, php-internals

Let me prefix this by saying that I know what `foreach` is, does and how to use it. This question concerns how it works under the bonnet, and I don't want any answers along the lines of "this is how you loop an array with `foreach`".

---

For a long time I assumed that `foreach` worked with the array itself. Then I found many references to the fact that it works with a *copy* of the array, and I have since assumed this to be the end of the story. But I recently got into a discussion on the matter, and after a little experimentation found that this was not in fact 100% true.

Let me show what I mean. For the following test cases, we will be working with the following array:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

[Test case 1](http://codepad.org/7DIeObk9):

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo "$item\n";
  $array[] = $item;
}
print_r($array);

/* Output in loop:    1 2 3 4 5
   $array after loop: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 */
```

This clearly shows that we are not working directly with the source array - otherwise the loop would continue forever, since we are constantly pushing items onto the array during the loop. But just to be sure this is the case:

[Test case 2](http://codepad.org/nirz6Ufh):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  $array[$key + 1] = $item + 2;
  echo "$item\n";
}

print_r($array);

/* Output in loop:    1 2 3 4 5
   $array after loop: 1 3 4 5 6 7 */
```

This backs up our initial conclusion, we are working with a copy of the source array during the loop, otherwise we would see the modified values during the loop. *But...*

If we look in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), we find this statement:

> When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array.

Right... this seems to suggest that `foreach` relies on the array pointer of the source array. But we've just proved that we're *not working with the source array*, right? Well, not entirely.

[Test case 3](http://codepad.org/6n20ooMy):

```
// Move the array pointer on one to make sure it doesn't affect the loop
var_dump(each($array));

foreach ($array as $item) {
  echo "$item\n";
}

var_dump(each($array));

/* Output
  array(4) {
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    ["value"]=>
    int(1)
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    ["key"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  bool(false)
*/
```

So, despite the fact that we are not working directly with the source array, we are working directly with the source array pointer - the fact that the pointer is at the end of the array at the end of the loop shows this. Except this can't be true - if it was, then [test case 1](http://codepad.org/7DIeObk9) would loop forever.

The PHP manual also states:

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

Well, let's find out what that "unexpected behavior" is (technically, any behavior is unexpected since I no longer know what to expect).

[Test case 4](http://codepad.org/JJp79xSd):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  echo "$item\n";
  each($array);
}

/* Output: 1 2 3 4 5 */
```

[Test case 5](http://codepad.org/IfwJyTCL):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  echo "$item\n";
  reset($array);
}

/* Output: 1 2 3 4 5 */
```

...nothing that unexpected there, in fact it seems to support the "copy of source" theory.

---

**The Question**

What is going on here? My C-fu is not good enough for me to able to extract a proper conclusion simply by looking at the PHP source code, I would appreciate it if someone could translate it into English for me.

It seems to me that `foreach` works with a *copy* of the array, but sets the array pointer of the source array to the end of the array after the loop.

- Is this correct and the whole story?
- If not, what is it really doing?
- Is there any situation where using functions that adjust the array pointer (`each()`, `reset()` et al.) during a `foreach` could affect the outcome of the loop?

Comment: @DaveRandom There's a [tag:php-internals] tag this should probably go with, but I'll leave it to you to decide which if any of the other 5 tags to replace.

Comment: try also `unset($array[$key + 1]);`

Comment: looks like COW, without delete handle

Comment: At first I thought »gosh, another newbie question. Read the docs… hm, clearly undefined behavior«. Then I read the complete question, and I must say: I like it. You've put quite some effort in it and writing all the testcases. ps. are testcase 4 and 5 the same?

Comment: @knittl Difference between 4 + 5 is `each()` vs `reset()` - trying to force it to skip an element or start from the beginning, respectively. Behavior it seems is identical for both though, the pointer of the source array is ignored.

Comment: @eicto Still no effect on the execution of the loop - http://codepad.org/y4hPzEw6. what do you mean by `looks like COW...` - can you elaborate?

Comment: @eicto Oh I see what you mean, thanks for the clarification. I think that is probably a sensible suggestion, although I'm still not sure how that would affect the source array's pointer. I didn't think you meant it looked like a black and white bovine, but it's as well to be sure ;-)

Comment: Just a thought about why it does make sense that the array pointer gets touched: PHP needs to reset and move the internal array pointer of the original array along with the copy, because the user may ask for a reference to the current value (`foreach ($array as &$value)`) - PHP needs to know the current position in the original array even though it's actually iterating over a copy.

Comment: this one looks more confusing http://codepad.org/RKFka0td

Comment: On a side note: Its not `C++`-fu, you need `C`-fu. :)

Comment: Actually, @OliCharlesworth, I would argue that PHP has the best documentation of just about any programming language in the world. There are plenty of reasons to hate on PHP but its documentation is not one of them.

Comment: @Sean: IMHO, the PHP documentation is really quite bad at describing the nuances of core language features.  But that is, perhaps, because so many ad-hoc special cases are baked into the language...

Comment: You are iterating over an array with refcount = 1 by reference, so it's immediately clear that a) no copy will be made and b) the array will be made a reference (removing the ref will cause the changes to not be visible inside the loop).

Comment: @monocell yes, I've re-read that again. But the thing is - it's not so clear for me that same mechanics of code evaluation (and pointer moving) order works in different ways.

Comment: @AlmaDo: this question is being discussed on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229549/is-this-rollback-justified

Comment: *(technically, any behavior is unexpected since I no longer know what to expect)* -- brilliant

Answer (score 1830, accepted):

`foreach` supports iteration over three different kinds of values:

- Arrays
- Normal objects
- [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable) objects

In the following, I will try to explain precisely how iteration works in different cases. By far the simplest case is `Traversable` objects, as for these `foreach` is essentially only syntax sugar for code along these lines:

```
foreach ($it as $k => $v) { /* ... */ }

/* translates to: */

if ($it instanceof IteratorAggregate) {
    $it = $it->getIterator();
}
for ($it->rewind(); $it->valid(); $it->next()) {
    $v = $it->current();
    $k = $it->key();
    /* ... */
}
```

For internal classes, actual method calls are avoided by using an internal API that essentially just mirrors the `Iterator` interface on the C level.

Iteration of arrays and plain objects is significantly more complicated. First of all, it should be noted that in PHP "arrays" are really ordered dictionaries and they will be traversed according to this order (which matches the insertion order as long as you didn't use something like `sort`). This is opposed to iterating by the natural order of the keys (how lists in other languages often work) or having no defined order at all (how dictionaries in other languages often work).

The same also applies to objects, as the object properties can be seen as another (ordered) dictionary mapping property names to their values, plus some visibility handling. In the majority of cases, the object properties are not actually stored in this rather inefficient way. However, if you start iterating over an object, the packed representation that is normally used will be converted to a real dictionary. At that point, iteration of plain objects becomes very similar to iteration of arrays (which is why I'm not discussing plain-object iteration much in here).

So far, so good. Iterating over a dictionary can't be too hard, right? The problems begin when you realize that an array/object can change during iteration. There are multiple ways this can happen:

- If you iterate by reference using `foreach ($arr as &$v)` then `$arr` is turned into a reference and you can change it during iteration.
- In PHP 5 the same applies even if you iterate by value, but the array was a reference beforehand: `$ref =& $arr; foreach ($ref as $v)`
- Objects have by-handle passing semantics, which for most practical purposes means that they behave like references. So objects can always be changed during iteration.

The problem with allowing modifications during iteration is the case where the element you are currently on is removed. Say you use a pointer to keep track of which array element you are currently at. If this element is now freed, you are left with a dangling pointer (usually resulting in a segfault).

There are different ways of solving this issue. PHP 5 and PHP 7 differ significantly in this regard and I'll describe both behaviors in the following. The summary is that PHP 5's approach was rather dumb and lead to all kinds of weird edge-case issues, while PHP 7's more involved approach results in more predictable and consistent behavior.

As a last preliminary, it should be noted that PHP uses reference counting and copy-on-write to manage memory. This means that if you "copy" a value, you actually just reuse the old value and increment its reference count (refcount). Only once you perform some kind of modification a real copy (called a "duplication") will be done. See [You're being lied to](http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html) for a more extensive introduction on this topic.

### PHP 5

#### Internal array pointer and HashPointer

Arrays in PHP 5 have one dedicated "internal array pointer" (IAP), which properly supports modifications: Whenever an element is removed, there will be a check whether the IAP points to this element. If it does, it is advanced to the next element instead.

While `foreach` does make use of the IAP, there is an additional complication: There is only one IAP, but one array can be part of multiple `foreach` loops:

```
// Using by-ref iteration here to make sure that it's really
// the same array in both loops and not a copy
foreach ($arr as &$v1) {
    foreach ($arr as &$v) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To support two simultaneous loops with only one internal array pointer, `foreach` performs the following shenanigans: Before the loop body is executed, `foreach` will back up a pointer to the current element and its hash into a per-foreach `HashPointer`. After the loop body runs, the IAP will be set back to this element if it still exists. If however the element has been removed, we'll just use wherever the IAP is currently at. This scheme mostly-kinda-sort of works, but there's a lot of weird behavior you can get out of it, some of which I'll demonstrate below.

#### Array duplication

The IAP is a visible feature of an array (exposed through the `current` family of functions), as such changes to the IAP count as modifications under copy-on-write semantics. This, unfortunately, means that `foreach` is in many cases forced to duplicate the array it is iterating over. The precise conditions are:

1. The array is not a reference (is_ref=0). If it's a reference, then changes to it are *supposed* to propagate, so it should not be duplicated.
2. The array has refcount>1. If `refcount` is 1, then the array is not shared and we're free to modify it directly.

If the array is not duplicated (is_ref=0, refcount=1), then only its `refcount` will be incremented (*). Additionally, if `foreach` by reference is used, then the (potentially duplicated) array will be turned into a reference.

Consider this code as an example where duplication occurs:

```
function iterate($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $v) {}
}

$outerArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
iterate($outerArr);
```

Here, `$arr` will be duplicated to prevent IAP changes on `$arr` from leaking to `$outerArr`. In terms of the conditions above, the array is not a reference (is_ref=0) and is used in two places (refcount=2). This requirement is unfortunate and an artifact of the suboptimal implementation (there is no concern of modification during iteration here, so we don't really need to use the IAP in the first place).

(*) Incrementing the `refcount` here sounds innocuous, but violates copy-on-write (COW) semantics: This means that we are going to modify the IAP of a refcount=2 array, while COW dictates that modifications can only be performed on refcount=1 values. This violation results in user-visible behavior change (while a COW is normally transparent) because the IAP change on the iterated array will be observable -- but only until the first non-IAP modification on the array. Instead, the three "valid" options would have been a) to always duplicate, b) do not increment the `refcount` and thus allowing the iterated array to be arbitrarily modified in the loop or c) don't use the IAP at all (the PHP 7 solution).

#### Position advancement order

There is one last implementation detail that you have to be aware of to properly understand the code samples below. The "normal" way of looping through some data structure would look something like this in pseudocode:

```
reset(arr);
while (get_current_data(arr, &data) == SUCCESS) {
    code();
    move_forward(arr);
}
```

However `foreach`, being a rather special snowflake, chooses to do things slightly differently:

```
reset(arr);
while (get_current_data(arr, &data) == SUCCESS) {
    move_forward(arr);
    code();
}
```

Namely, the array pointer is already moved forward *before* the loop body runs. This means that while the loop body is working on element `$i`, the IAP is already at element `$i+1`. This is the reason why code samples showing modification during iteration will always `unset` the *next* element, rather than the current one.

#### Examples: Your test cases

The three aspects described above should provide you with a mostly complete impression of the idiosyncrasies of the `foreach` implementation and we can move on to discuss some examples.

The behavior of your test cases is simple to explain at this point:

- In test cases 1 and 2 `$array` starts off with refcount=1, so it will not be duplicated by `foreach`: Only the `refcount` is incremented. When the loop body subsequently modifies the array (which has refcount=2 at that point), the duplication will occur at that point. Foreach will continue working on an unmodified copy of `$array`.
- In test case 3, once again the array is not duplicated, thus `foreach` will be modifying the IAP of the `$array` variable. At the end of the iteration, the IAP is NULL (meaning iteration has done), which `each` indicates by returning `false`.
- In test cases 4 and 5 both `each` and `reset` are by-reference functions. The `$array` has a `refcount=2` when it is passed to them, so it has to be duplicated. As such `foreach` will be working on a separate array again.

#### Examples: Effects of `current` in foreach

A good way to show the various duplication behaviors is to observe the behavior of the  `current()` function inside a `foreach` loop. Consider this example:

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
/* Output: 2 2 2 2 2 */
```

Here you should know that `current()` is a by-ref function (actually: prefer-ref), even though it does not modify the array. It has to be in order to play nice with all the other functions like `next` which are all by-ref. By-reference passing implies that the array has to be separated and thus `$array` and the `foreach-array` will be different. The reason you get `2` instead of `1` is also mentioned above: `foreach` advances the array pointer *before* running the user code, not after. So even though the code is at the first element, `foreach` already advanced the pointer to the second.

Now lets try a small modification:

```
$ref = &$array;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
/* Output: 2 3 4 5 false */
```

Here we have the is_ref=1 case, so the array is not copied (just like above). But now that it is a reference, the array no longer has to be duplicated when passing to the by-ref `current()` function. Thus `current()` and `foreach` work on the same array. You still see the off-by-one behavior though, due to the way `foreach` advances the pointer.

You get the same behavior when doing by-ref iteration:

```
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
/* Output: 2 3 4 5 false */
```

Here the important part is that foreach will make `$array` an is_ref=1 when it is iterated by reference, so basically you have the same situation as above.

Another small variation, this time we'll assign the array to another variable:

```
$foo = $array;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
/* Output: 1 1 1 1 1 */
```

Here the refcount of the `$array` is 2 when the loop is started, so for once we actually have to do the duplication upfront. Thus `$array` and the array used by foreach will be completely separate from the outset. That's why you get the position of the IAP wherever it was before the loop (in this case it was at the first position).

#### Examples: Modification during iteration

Trying to account for modifications during iteration is where all our foreach troubles originated, so it serves to consider some examples for this case.

Consider these nested loops over the same array (where by-ref iteration is used to make sure it really is the same one):

```
foreach ($array as &$v1) {
    foreach ($array as &$v2) {
        if ($v1 == 1 && $v2 == 1) {
            unset($array[1]);
        }
        echo "($v1, $v2)\n";
    }
}

// Output: (1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5)
```

The expected part here is that `(1, 2)` is missing from the output because element `1` was removed. What's probably unexpected is that the outer loop stops after the first element. Why is that?

The reason behind this is the nested-loop hack described above: Before the loop body runs, the current IAP position and hash is backed up into a `HashPointer`. After the loop body it will be restored, but only if the element still exists, otherwise the current IAP position (whatever it may be) is used instead. In the example above this is exactly the case: The current element of the outer loop has been removed, so it will use the IAP, which has already been marked as finished by the inner loop!

Another consequence of the `HashPointer` backup+restore mechanism is that changes to the IAP through `reset()` etc. usually do not impact `foreach`. For example, the following code executes as if the `reset()` were not present at all:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    var_dump($value);
    reset($array);
}
// output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The reason is that, while `reset()` temporarily modifies the IAP, it will be restored to the current foreach element after the loop body. To force `reset()` to make an effect on the loop, you have to additionally remove the current element, so that the backup/restore mechanism fails:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$ref =& $array;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    unset($array[1]);
    reset($array);
}
// output: 1, 1, 3, 4, 5
```

But, those examples are still sane. The real fun starts if you remember that the `HashPointer` restore uses a pointer to the element and its hash to determine whether it still exists. But: Hashes have collisions, and pointers can be reused! This means that, with a careful choice of array keys, we can make `foreach` believe that an element that has been removed still exists, so it will jump directly to it. An example:

```
$array = ['EzEz' => 1, 'EzFY' => 2, 'FYEz' => 3];
$ref =& $array;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    unset($array['EzFY']);
    $array['FYFY'] = 4;
    reset($array);
    var_dump($value);
}
// output: 1, 4
```

Here we should normally expect the output `1, 1, 3, 4` according to the previous rules. How what happens is that `'FYFY'` has the same hash as the removed element `'EzFY'`, and the allocator happens to reuse the same memory location to store the element. So foreach ends up directly jumping to the newly inserted element, thus short-cutting the loop.

#### Substituting the iterated entity during the loop

One last odd case that I'd like to mention, it is that PHP allows you to substitute the iterated entity during the loop. So you can start iterating on one array and then replace it with another array halfway through. Or start iterating on an array and then replace it with an object:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$obj = (object) [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$ref =& $arr;
foreach ($ref as $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
    if ($val == 3) {
        $ref = $obj;
    }
}
/* Output: 1 2 3 6 7 8 9 10 */
```

As you can see in this case PHP will just start iterating the other entity from the start once the substitution has happened.

### PHP 7

#### Hashtable iterators

If you still remember, the main problem with array iteration was how to handle removal of elements mid-iteration. PHP 5 used a single internal array pointer (IAP) for this purpose, which was somewhat suboptimal, as one array pointer had to be stretched to support multiple simultaneous foreach loops *and* interaction with `reset()` etc. on top of that.

PHP 7 uses a different approach, namely, it supports creating an arbitrary amount of external, safe hashtable iterators. These iterators have to be registered in the array, from which point on they have the same semantics as the IAP: If an array element is removed, all hashtable iterators pointing to that element will be advanced to the next element.

This means that `foreach` will no longer use the IAP **at all**. The `foreach` loop will be absolutely no effect on the results of `current()` etc. and its own behavior will never be influenced by functions like  `reset()` etc.

#### Array duplication

Another important change between PHP 5 and PHP 7 relates to array duplication. Now that the IAP is no longer used, by-value array iteration will only do a `refcount` increment (instead of duplication the array) in all cases. If the array is modified during the `foreach` loop, at that point a duplication will occur (according to copy-on-write) and `foreach` will keep working on the old array.

In most cases, this change is transparent and has no other effect than better performance. However, there is one occasion where it results in different behavior, namely the case where the array was a reference beforehand:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$ref = &$array;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    var_dump($val);
    $array[2] = 0;
}
/* Old output: 1, 2, 0, 4, 5 */
/* New output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 */
```

Previously by-value iteration of reference-arrays was special cases. In this case, no duplication occurred, so all modifications of the array during iteration would be reflected by the loop. In PHP 7 this special case is gone: A by-value iteration of an array will **always** keep working on the original elements, disregarding any modifications during the loop.

This, of course, does not apply to by-reference iteration. If you iterate by-reference all modifications will be reflected by the loop. Interestingly, the same is true for by-value iteration of plain objects:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->foo = 1;
$obj->bar = 2;
foreach ($obj as $val) {
    var_dump($val);
    $obj->bar = 42;
}
/* Old and new output: 1, 42 */
```

This reflects the by-handle semantics of objects (i.e. they behave reference-like even in by-value contexts).

#### Examples

Let's consider a few examples, starting with your test cases:

- Test cases 1 and 2 retain the same output: By-value array iteration always keep working on the original elements. (In this case, even `refcounting` and duplication behavior is exactly the same between PHP 5 and PHP 7).
- Test case 3 changes: `Foreach` no longer uses the IAP, so `each()` is not affected by the loop. It will have the same output before and after.
- Test cases 4 and 5 stay the same: `each()` and `reset()` will duplicate the array before changing the IAP, while `foreach` still uses the original array. (Not that the IAP change would have mattered, even if the array was shared.)

The second set of examples was related to the behavior of `current()` under different `reference/refcounting` configurations. This no longer makes sense, as `current()` is completely unaffected by the loop, so its return value always stays the same.

However, we get some interesting changes when considering modifications during iteration. I hope you will find the new behavior saner. The first example:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
foreach ($array as &$v1) {
    foreach ($array as &$v2) {
        if ($v1 == 1 && $v2 == 1) {
            unset($array[1]);
        }
        echo "($v1, $v2)\n";
    }
}

// Old output: (1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5)
// New output: (1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5)
//             (3, 1) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5)
//             (4, 1) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5)
//             (5, 1) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5)
```

As you can see, the outer loop no longer aborts after the first iteration. The reason is that both loops now have entirely separate hashtable iterators, and there is no longer any cross-contamination of both loops through a shared IAP.

Another weird edge case that is fixed now, is the odd effect you get when you remove and add elements that happen to have the same hash:

```
$array = ['EzEz' => 1, 'EzFY' => 2, 'FYEz' => 3];
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    unset($array['EzFY']);
    $array['FYFY'] = 4;
    var_dump($value);
}
// Old output: 1, 4
// New output: 1, 3, 4
```

Previously the HashPointer restore mechanism jumped right to the new element because it "looked" like it's the same as the removed element (due to colliding hash and pointer). As we no longer rely on the element hash for anything, this is no longer an issue.

Comment: @Baba It does. Passing it to a function is the same as doing `$foo = $array` before the loop ;)

Comment: foreach seems to save the position of the array in a `HashPointer` struct after an iteration and restores it before an iteration. The struct carries a `HashPosition` and the `h` of the bucket pointed to by the `HashPosition`. The hash is used to verify that the bucket is still in the table, so a `HashPointer` is safe to use even after array modification. That's probably why we can see the modified array position (`each()` returning null after foreach), and also why attempting to modify it doesn't affect foreach.

Comment: @arnaud576875 Good point, I forgot to mention that. Though I don't see how it is related to "see the modified array position (each() returning null after foreach)". That's just an effect of it using the IAP. Afaik it's just there to prevent next/prev calls in the foreach body from changing the position (in the ref case).

Comment: For those of you who don't know what a zval is, please refer to Sara Goleman's http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html

Comment: @arnaud576875 I added some explanation (and even more weirdness!) regarding HashPointer at the end (starting with the last heading)

Comment: Minor correction: what you call Bucket isn't what is normally called Bucket in a hashtable. Normally Bucket is a set of entries with the same hash%size. You seem to use it for what is normally called an entry. Linked list isn't on buckets, but on entries.

Comment: @unbeli I'm using the terminology used internally by PHP. The `Bucket`s are part of a doubly linked list for hash collisions and also part of a doubly linked list for order ;)

Answer (score 128):

In example 3 you don't modify the array. In all other examples you modify either the contents or the internal array pointer. This is important when it comes to [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) arrays because of the semantics of the assignment operator.

The assignment operator for the arrays in PHP works more like a lazy clone. Assigning one variable to another that contains an array will clone the array, unlike most languages. However, the actual cloning will not be done unless it is needed. This means that the clone will take place only when either of the variables is modified (copy-on-write).

Here is an example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = $a;  // This is lazy cloning of $a. For the time
          // being $a and $b point to the same internal
          // data structure.

$a[] = 3; // Here $a changes, which triggers the actual
          // cloning. From now on, $a and $b are two
          // different data structures. The same would
          // happen if there were a change in $b.
```

Coming back to your test cases, you can easily imagine that `foreach` creates some kind of iterator with a reference to the array. This reference works exactly like the variable `$b` in my example. However, the iterator along with the reference live only during the loop and then, they are both discarded. Now you can see that, in all cases but 3, the array is modified during the loop, while this extra reference is alive. This triggers a clone, and that explains what's going on here!

Here is an excellent article for another side effect of this copy-on-write behaviour: [The PHP Ternary Operator: Fast or not?](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not)

Comment: seems your right, I made some example which demonstrate that: 
http://codepad.org/OCjtvu8r one difference from your example - it does not copy if you change value, only if change keys.

Comment: This does indeed explain all the behavior show above, and it can be nicely illustrated by calling `each()` at the end of the first test case, where [we see](http://codepad.org/XNlmCPE9) that the array pointer of the original array points to the second element, since the array was modified during the first iteration. This also seems to demonstrate that `foreach` moves the array pointer on before executing the code block of the loop, which I was not expecting - I would have thought it would do this at the end. Many thanks, this clears it up for me nicely.

Answer (score 57):

Some points to note when working with `foreach()`:

a) `foreach` works on the **prospected copy** of the original array.
    It means `foreach()` will have SHARED data storage until or unless a `prospected copy` is
    not created [foreach Notes/User comments](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

b) What triggers a **prospected copy**?
    A prospected copy is created based on the policy of `copy-on-write`, that is, whenever
    an array passed to `foreach()` is changed, a clone of the original array is created.

c) The original array and `foreach()` iterator will have `DISTINCT SENTINEL VARIABLES`, that is, one for the original array and other for `foreach`; see the test code below. [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) , [Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), and [Array Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php).

Stack Overflow question *[How to make sure the value is reset in a 'foreach' loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728709)* addresses the cases (3,4,5) of your question.

The following example shows that each() and reset() DOES NOT affect `SENTINEL` variables
`(for example, the current index variable)` of the `foreach()` iterator.

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

list($key2, $val2) = each($array);
echo "each() Original (outside): $key2 => $val2<br/>";

foreach($array as $key => $val){
    echo "foreach: $key => $val<br/>";

    list($key2,$val2) = each($array);
    echo "each() Original(inside): $key2 => $val2<br/>";

    echo "--------Iteration--------<br/>";
    if ($key == 3){
        echo "Resetting original array pointer<br/>";
        reset($array);
    }
}

list($key2, $val2) = each($array);
echo "each() Original (outside): $key2 => $val2<br/>";
```

**Output:**

```
each() Original (outside): 0 => 1
foreach: 0 => 1
each() Original(inside): 1 => 2
--------Iteration--------
foreach: 1 => 2
each() Original(inside): 2 => 3
--------Iteration--------
foreach: 2 => 3
each() Original(inside): 3 => 4
--------Iteration--------
foreach: 3 => 4
each() Original(inside): 4 => 5
--------Iteration--------
Resetting original array pointer
foreach: 4 => 5
each() Original(inside): 0=>1
--------Iteration--------
each() Original (outside): 1 => 2
```

Comment: Your answer is not quite correct. `foreach` operates on a potential copy of the array, but it does not make the actual copy unless it is needed.

Comment: would you like to demonstrate how and when that potential copy is created through code ? My code demonstrates that `foreach` is copying the array  100% of the time. I am eager to know. Thanks for you comments

Comment: Copying an array costs a lot. Try counting the time it takes to iterate an array with 100000 elements using either `for` or `foreach`. You will not see any significant difference between the two of them, because an actual copy does not take place.

Comment: Then I would assume that there is `SHARED data storage` reserved until or unless `copy-on-write` , but (from my code snippet) its evident that there will always be TWO set of `SENTINEL variables` one for the `original array` and other for `foreach`. Thanks that makes sense

Comment: "prospected"? Do you mean "protected"?

Comment: yes that is "prospected" copy i.e "potential" copy.Its not protected as you suggested

Answer (score 41):

**NOTE FOR PHP 7**

To update on this answer as it has gained some popularity: This answer no longer applies as of PHP 7. As explained in the "[Backward incompatible changes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)", in PHP 7 foreach works on copy of the array, so any changes on the array itself are not reflected on foreach loop. More details at the link.

**Explanation (quote from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):**

> The first form loops over the array given by array_expression. On each
>   iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $value and
>   the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next
>   iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

So, in your first example you only have one element in the array, and when the pointer is moved the next element does not exist, so after you add new element foreach ends because it already "decided" that it it as the last element.

In your second example, you start with two elements, and foreach loop is not at the last element so it evaluates the array on the next iteration and thus realises that there is new element in the array.

I believe that this is all consequence of **On each iteration** part of the explanation in the documentation, which probably means that `foreach` does all logic before it calls the code in `{}`.

**Test case**

If you run this:

```
<?
    $array = Array(
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => 2
    );
    foreach($array as $k=>&$v) {
        $array['baz']=3;
        echo $v." ";
    }
    print_r($array);
?>
```

You will get this output:

```
1 2 3 Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [bar] => 2
    [baz] => 3
)
```

Which means that it accepted the modification and went through it because it was modified "in time". But if you do this:

```
<?
    $array = Array(
        'foo' => 1,
        'bar' => 2
    );
    foreach($array as $k=>&$v) {
        if ($k=='bar') {
            $array['baz']=3;
        }
        echo $v." ";
    }
    print_r($array);
?>
```

You will get:

```
1 2 Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [bar] => 2
    [baz] => 3
)
```

Which means that array was modified, but since we modified it when the `foreach` already was at the last element of the array, it "decided" not to loop anymore, and even though we added new element, we added it "too late" and it was not looped through.

Detailed explanation can be read at [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works) which explains the internals behind this behaviour.

Comment: Well did you read the rest of the answer? It makes perfect sense that foreach decides if it will loop another time **before** it even runs the code in it.

Comment: No, the array is modified, but "too late" since foreach already "thinks" that it is at the last element (which it is at the start of iteration) and will not loop anymore. Where in the second example, it is not at the last element at the start of iteration and evaluates again on the start of next iteration. I am trying to prepare a test case.

Comment: @AlmaDo Look at http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#4509 It's always set to the next pointer when it iterates. So, when it reaches the last iteration, it'll be marked as finished (via NULL pointer). When you then add a key in last iteration, foreach won't notice it.

Comment: @AlmaDo if you want internal reasons read them from accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works and I will update my answer to include this.

Comment: @DKasipovic no. There is no _complete & clear_ explanation there (at least for now - may be I'm wrong)

Comment: I don't agree, however it is up to you. In the other answer and in my answer there is everything explained. Even my example proves what I said. I don't see what the problem is here. Maybe I dont understand you very well.

Comment: Actually it seems that @AlmaDo has a flaw in understanding his own logic… Your answer is fine.

Comment: @Damir can you update you answer, cause your second example give the same output like first for PHP version >= 7

Comment: @circleandsquare in the "Backward incompatible changes" ( https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php ) there is an explanation on how foreach works in PHP 7, I think it explains it pretty well. Basically, in PHP 7 foreach works on copy of the array, so any changes on the array itself are not reflected on foreach loop.

Comment: @Damir I agree with you about answer, just because this is one of top visited question I suggest you to improve your answer with mention about PHP version, cause this will confuse new ones.

Answer (score 18):

As per the documentation provided by PHP manual.

> On each iteration, the value of the current element is assigned to $v and the internal
>   array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next iteration, you'll be looking at the next element).

So as per your first example:

```
$array = ['foo'=>1];
foreach($array as $k=>&$v)
{
   $array['bar']=2;
   echo($v);
}
```

`$array` have only single element, so as per the foreach execution, 1 assign to `$v` and it don't have any other element to move pointer

But in your second example:

```
$array = ['foo'=>1, 'bar'=>2];
foreach($array as $k=>&$v)
{
   $array['baz']=3;
   echo($v);
}
```

`$array` have two element, so now $array evaluate the zero indices and move the pointer by one. For first iteration of loop, added `$array['baz']=3;` as pass by reference.

Answer (score 15):

Great question, because many developers, even experienced ones, are confused by the way PHP handles arrays in foreach loops. In the standard foreach loop, PHP makes a copy of the array that is used in the loop. The copy is discarded immediately after the loop finishes. This is transparent in the operation of a simple foreach loop. 
For example:

```
$set = array("apple", "banana", "coconut");
foreach ( $set AS $item ) {
    echo "{$item}\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
apple
banana
coconut
```

So the copy is created but the developer doesn't notice, because the original array isn’t referenced within the loop or after the loop finishes. However, when you attempt to modify the items in a loop, you find that they are unmodified when you finish:

```
$set = array("apple", "banana", "coconut");
foreach ( $set AS $item ) {
    $item = strrev ($item);
}

print_r($set);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [2] => coconut
)
```

Any changes from the original can't be notices, actually there are no changes from the original, even though you clearly assigned a value to $item. This is because you are operating on $item as it appears in the copy of $set being worked on. You can override this by grabbing $item by reference, like so:

```
$set = array("apple", "banana", "coconut");
foreach ( $set AS &$item ) {
    $item = strrev($item);
}
print_r($set);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => elppa
    [1] => ananab
    [2] => tunococ
)
```

So it is evident and observable, when $item is operated on by-reference, the changes made to $item are made to the members of the original $set. Using $item by reference also prevents PHP from creating the array copy. To test this, first we’ll show a quick script demonstrating the copy:

```
$set = array("apple", "banana", "coconut");
foreach ( $set AS $item ) {
    $set[] = ucfirst($item);
}
print_r($set);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [2] => coconut
    [3] => Apple
    [4] => Banana
    [5] => Coconut
)
```

As it is shown in the example, PHP copied $set and used it to loop over, but when $set was used inside the loop, PHP added the variables to the original array, not the copied array. Basically, PHP is only using the copied array for the execution of the loop and the assignment of $item. Because of this, the loop above only executes 3 times, and each time it appends another value to the end of the original $set, leaving the original $set with 6 elements, but never entering an infinite loop.

However, what if we had used $item by reference, as I mentioned before? A single character added to the above test:

```
$set = array("apple", "banana", "coconut");
foreach ( $set AS &$item ) {
    $set[] = ucfirst($item);
}
print_r($set);
```

Results in an infinite loop. Note this actually is an infinite loop, you’ll have to either kill the script yourself or wait for your OS to run out of memory. I added the following line to my script so PHP would run out of memory very quickly, I suggest you do the same if you’re going to be running these infinite loop tests:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1M");
```

So in this previous example with the infinite loop, we see the reason why PHP was written to create a copy of the array to loop over. When a copy is created and used only by the structure of the loop construct itself, the array stays static throughout the execution of the loop, so you’ll never run into issues.

Answer (score 10):

PHP foreach loop can be used with `Indexed arrays`, `Associative arrays` and `Object public variables`.

In foreach loop, the first thing php does is that it creates a copy of the array which is to be iterated over. PHP then iterates over this new `copy` of the array rather than the original one. This is demonstrated in the below example:

```
<?php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; # initial values for our array
echo '<pre>', print_r($numbers, true), '</pre>', '<hr />';
foreach($numbers as $index => $number){
    $numbers[$index] = $number + 1; # this is making changes to the origial array
    echo 'Inside of the array = ', $index, ': ', $number, '<br />'; # showing data from the copied array
}
echo '<hr />', '<pre>', print_r($numbers, true), '</pre>'; # shows the original values (also includes the newly added values).
```

Besides this, php does allow to use `iterated values as a reference to the original array value` as well. This is demonstrated below:

```
<?php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
echo '<pre>', print_r($numbers, true), '</pre>';
foreach($numbers as $index => &$number){
    ++$number; # we are incrementing the original value
    echo 'Inside of the array = ', $index, ': ', $number, '<br />'; # this is showing the original value
}
echo '<hr />';
echo '<pre>', print_r($numbers, true), '</pre>'; # we are again showing the original value
```

**Note:** It does not allow `original array indexes` to be used as `references`.

Source: http://dwellupper.io/post/47/understanding-php-foreach-loop-with-examples

Comment: `Object public variables` is wrong or at best misleading. You cannot use an object in an array without the correct interface (eg, Traversible) and when you do `foreach((array)$obj ...` you are in fact working with a simple array, not an object anymore.